# Tiki this Riemann surface picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone help me with drawing an image like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#/media/File:Riemann_surface_log.svg

with tikz?

I'm quite comfortable with two dimensional tikz diagrams, but to generate a spiral like this seems quite confusing and out of my league.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a questions and answers site, not a place to dump your work.  You can take a look at [TeX Consulting and Production Services](https://www.tug.org/consultants.html) to find people who will do such things for you (for money of course).

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't want someone to do it for me... I just have no experience with these types of plots and would like some help on how one would go about it. Also, this is not "work", I am practising tikz in my own time.

Comment: You can do surface plots with `pgfplots`, so maybe that can help. If you have an expression to plot.

Comment: @Alanna Then why don't you show what you have achieved so far by reading the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Do you have a reference for parametric plots with pgfplots? I want to plot the curve $\bold{r}(u,v) = \langle u \cos v, u \sin v, v \rangle$. The link you provided only works for single valued functions.

Comment: I didn't provide any link at all, what are you talking about? If you're referring to the manual, there are some examples of that I think in section 4.6.2 about the `\addplot3` command.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    unbounded coords=jump,
    z filter/.expression={z > pi - 1e-2 ? nan : z},
    domain=-1:1,
    y domain=-1:1]
    \addplot3[surf] {atan2(y,x)/180*pi};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]